# Temporary Library Search Path in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, dynamic-linking

I've got multiple version of the same library to which my program dynamically links. Sometimes I'd like to change the version that gets used.

I've been reading that new versions of Ubuntu no longer support `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for security reasons. I could add the path to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and run `ldconfig` but I won't always have root privileges on the system.

Anyone know how to make a change to the library search path, that a plain user can make? Assume that it happens often enough that updating config files is a last resort.

Edit: Here is how I'm testing, what I expect to see and so on: I run `ldd` on a program and see `libfoo.so => /some/path/to/lib/libfoo.so`. I prepend `/path/to/different/version/lib` (which contains a file named libfoo.so) to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and rerun `ldd`. The path for libfoo.so is the same as before when I'd expect to see `libfoo.so => /path/to/different/version/lib/libfoo.so`.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [patchelf](http://nixos.org/patchelf.html) to change the `RPATH` (library search path) of any executable. It's a cool utility, and does not require special privileges to run. To set a program to first search `/opt/my-libs/lib` then `/foo/lib`, just do this:

```
% patchelf --set-rpath /opt/my-libs/lib:/foo/lib program
```

Comment: I'm building the executable from source, so I can change compilation/linking options if that would help. Is RPATH based on the -L option at compile-time? There is a -Wl,-R/path/to/lib which I don't understand. Just to be clear, based on the docs, what I'm trying to do _should_ work, right?

Comment: It just seems like there should be a way to give the program a default, yet let the user override it at runtime if they'd like.

Comment: Linking with the RPATH (as described) will hard-code the library search path as desired. The main problem is changing it, which you can do by re-linking or by using patchelf.

Comment: I'm confused then about the usefulness of LD_LIBRARY_PATH. The paths in there are only searched if there is no RPATH specified at link-time?

Comment: Per Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rpath_(linking)), "the primary disadvantage of using RPATH is that it has higher priority than the LD_LIBRARY_PATH settings."